# How can I fix the #c3284d# malvertising hack on my website?

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-chrome, malware

For the past couple of weeks at semi regular intervals, [this](http://www.melfordschoolofmotoring.co.uk) website has had the **#c3284d#** malware code inserted into some of its .php files. Also the .htaccess file had its equivelant code inserted. I have, on many occasions removed the malicious code, replaced files, changed the ftp password on my ftp client (which is CoreFTP), changed the connection method to FTPS for more secure storage of the password (instead of plain text).

I have also scanned my computer several times using AVG and Windows Defender which have found no malware on my computer which might have been storing my ftp passwords.

I used [Sucuri SiteCheck](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/www.melfordschoolofmotoring.co.uk) to check my website which says my website is clean of malware which is bizarre because I just attempted to click one of the links on the site a minute ago and it linked me to another one of these random stats.php sites, even though it appears I have gotten rid of the #c3284d# code again (which will no doubt be re-inserted somehow in an hour or so)..

Has anyone found an actual viable solution for this malware hack?

I have done just about all of the things suggested [here](http://www.gadgehit.com/2012/07/23/how-to-fix-c3284d-stats-php-malware-issues/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=how-to-fix-c3284d-stats-php-malware-issues) and [here](http://stopmalvertising.com/malware-reports/the-c3284d-malware-network-stats.php.html) and the problem still persists.

Currently when I click on a link within the sites navigation menu within Google Chrome I get googles Malware warning page:

> Warning: Something's Not Right Here! oxsanasiberians.com contains
>   malware. Your computer might catch a virus if you visit this site.
>   Google has found that malicious software may be installed onto your
>   computer if you proceed. If you've visited this site in the past or
>   you trust this site, it's possible that it has just recently been
>   compromised by a hacker. You should not proceed. Why not try again
>   tomorrow or go somewhere else? We have already notified
>   oxsanasiberians.com that we found malware on the site. For more about
>   the problems found on oxsanasiberians.com, visit the Google Safe
>   Browsing diagnostic page.

Comment: Study your access logs. If you know how to read the logs you will find suspicious accesses in it.

Answer (score 2):

I haved exact the same problem.

I guess the site was infected through the widgets, because I use one plugin wich allows PHP code to be executed.

My best solution was:

> ```
> -eliminate the suspicious widget;
> -see the time and date of one infected file(my case: header.php); 
> -clear all infected files(in my case I have a backup of the site); 
> -search into log file for suspicious IPs at that time (search finded IPs on blacklists); 
> -install one plugin to ban suspicious IPs.
> ```

From that moment the problem was gone.

Comment: +1 A shocking number of WP plugins have terrible/sloppy coding and more use of the `eval` function that I would ever like to see (if at all.) Updating these plugins don't help if the security holes aren't being addressed. Only use well-respected popular plugins, and keep an eye on the reviews for mentions of security holes.

Answer (score 1):

> I used Sucuri SiteCheck to check my website which says my website is clean of malware which is bizarre because I just attempted to click one of the links on the site a minute ago and it linked me to another one of these random stats.php sites, even though it appears I have gotten rid of the #c3284d# code again (which will no doubt be re-inserted somehow in an hour or so)..

1. Did you click re-scan? Because the site caches results for 24 hours.
2. Did you clear your website's cache? For example if you use Super Cache plugin or something.
3. When you changed the FTP password through your CPanel, did you try NOT logging in for a day or so? This would verify whether the problem was FTP-password based. I recently tried to log into my FTP through Filezilla after clearing this infection, and I immediately deleted the website entry after it. The next day my site was infected again. So I've decided to do everything through cPanel from now on.